# PostgreSQL cannot drop index on partition

Tags: postgresql, partitioning, indexing

I have several partition tables with indexes on them. All indexes can be seen in response of

```
SELECT indexname FROM pg_catalog.pg_indexes;
```

But when I'm trying to make `DROP INDEX my_index_name;` it returns error declaring that there is no index my_index_name.
How can I drop those indexes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be related to your `search_path`. Try dropping the index prefixed by the schema.

Eg.

`SELECT schemaname,tablename,indexname FROM pg_indexes WHERE indexname = 'my_index_name'`

Using the results of that query, drop the index:

`DROP INDEX some_schema.your_index_name;`